# Why starting some programs takes too long after windows start?

Tags: boot, windows-8, uac

Every time I restart my computer (which it has an SSD hard drive) it takes about few seconds to windows 8 boot and login. But I cannot start some programs like Task Manager, Services, Any Run as Administrator. But some programs like chrome, file explorer, ... works. For example I run as administrator a notepad after login, it takes about 60-120 seconds to "User account control" confirm message dialog appears. After that every thing is fine. I am suspicious that may be one of the related windows service is in "Automatic Delayed Start" mode. but I don't know which one.

**Edited**
I monitored the event log after windows logon, this message was logged after 1 minute :
The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) did not load:
cdrom
dam
NetworkX
UdfReadr

what are these drivers and how can I disable driver load?(Also I don't have any cd-rom)

Comment: Look in Task Manager and see what the status of Notepad is. That is one starting point.

Comment: @John I tried to open Task Manager but that does not appear also until  a period of time. Even I tried services.msc command but after about 30 seconds all the windows opened together.

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run SFC  /SCANNOW  .  Restart when done and test.

Comment: If you can't identify the service as a workaround you could use hibernate (suspend to disk). Then all services would be directly available after "boot". I am using hibernate for years and don't understand why I should restore everything every day again.

Comment: Part of the changes made to recent Windows versions included making Windows able to log in before all of its various processes were completed, so if you log in right away there will still be necessary start up processes running in the background for a bit. You can use Windows' boot analyzer tool to see what is still running and where you could improve things.

Comment: @John I run the SFC command and restart but nothing changed

Comment: @music2myear I have multiple device with windows 8 and 10 in my company and no one has this problem and have never seen that after about 60-120 seconds windows boot.

Comment: @Zatkhahi you made no indication that you deal with multiple systems or whether or not it occurred on multiple systems. A 2 minute Windows boot is bad for any hardware less than 10 years old. Please do as we suggest and use the boot analyzer tools we mentioned.